# How to save value get from socket to a variable C++

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client

I am doing socket programming in C++.

Alice is host and Bob is client. I tried to send the public key of Bob to Alice using read() and write() function. However it only displays the public to the terminal if I used printf. (bobpuk is char[]) where I want to save the bobpuk as variable for further processing. I tried to copy it to string but it does not display anything on screen. This is my code for the program:

Server.cpp

```
 valread = read( newsockfd , bobpuk, strlen(bobpuk));
    if (valread < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

    printf("%s",bobpuk);
    cout << bobpuk;
    string str="";
    for(int i=0; i < strlen(bobpuk); i++)
    {
        str+= bobpuk[i];
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << "STRING: " << str << endl;
```

Client.cpp:

```
n= write(sockfd, puk, strlen(puk));
if (n=0) error ("ERROR reading from socket");
```

Comment: Does the first cout print bobpuk correctly?

Comment: It does not print anything, only printf function prints out the public key

Comment: what happens if you use only printfs instead of cout?

Comment: it can display the value, however i want to use the value for further encryption instead of only displaying on the screen. Do i need to use send() and recv()? I tried with those two and it also does not work

Comment: If bobpuk is a void*, then it may not work well with std::string. So better use strcpy to copy from it.